# .NET Unit Tests - MongoDB collection service should be tested

Tags: asp.net, mongodb, unit-testing, mocking

I'm looking for best practice advices on code coverage.

I'm faced with a question on which I can't agree with myself.
For each of my MongoDB collections, I have a "Storage Service" that contains methods that performs the database queries.
Should these methods be unit tested or not?

**Why shouldn't I?**

*Each method simply makes a MongoDB query, which I'll have to mock to perform the unit test.
So my unit test will be to check that the method's return value is indeed the one the mock intended to return. It's obvious.
Wouldn't it be simpler to exclude "Storage Services" from code coverage?*

For examples, methods from Profiles *Storage Service*

```
public async Task<Profile?> GetByUserIdAsync(string userId)
{
    return await _collection
        .Find(x => x.UserId == userId && x.Type == ProfileType.Consumer)
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
}

public async Task<Profile> CreateAsync(Profile profile)
{
    return await _collection
        .FindOneAndReplaceAsync<Profile>(
            x => x.UserId == profile.UserId,
            profile,
            new FindOneAndReplaceOptions<Profile>
            {
                IsUpsert = true,
                ReturnDocument = ReturnDocument.After
            });
}
```

or from Items *Storage Service*

```
public async Task<List<Item>> FetchAsync(Pagination page)
{
    return await _collection
        .Find(x => x.Active == true)
        .Skip(page.Offset)
        .Limit(page.Limit)
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

or from Orders *Storage Service*

```
public async Task<Order> CreateAsync(Order order)
{
    await _collection.InsertOneAsync(order);
    return order;
}
```

For example, I tried to unit test `public async Task<Order> CreateAsync(Order order)`

> I mocked `_collection` object and setup `InsertOneAsync` method to return the order given in parameter. Simple procedure and **obvious** result.

For example, I tried to unit test `public async Task<List<Item>> FetchAsync(Pagination page)`

> I mocked `_collection` object and underlying object such as `ICursorAsync` that `ToListAync` extensions would return the list of items defined by the test. Harder procedure and **obvious** result and I can't test the `Find` predicate behavior, and can't test `Skip` and `Limit` extensions behavior.

So I came to the conclusion that these tests were useless.

But I may have done something wrong or misunderstood something. That's why I need your advice.